# import greendroid eclipse

Tags: android, greendroid

I know there are other topics addressing the problems in imports greendroid, but I'm in serious trouble and I would ask humbly to those who already use the greendroid able to help me. I've watched many tutorials on the Internet showing how to import but even doing what he was saying did not work there.
att,

Comment: what errors have you encountered?

Comment: brother, he points out errors in some folders and asks to configure buildpath. So I go there and set up. Then when I owned, android and I click to add a library there is no library available.
I will give it in the design and March greendroid Fix Project Properties. From now on, when I go back into properties> android he starts giving this error: ClassExample already exists but is not a source folder. Convert to a source folder or rename it.

There is no step-by-step what you do and be sure to work?

Comment: it's a d little difficult to describe here. 
1. First, ensure the GreenDroid doesn't throw errors and configure it to be a Library project.
2. import it into your project. Have a try~

But I think you'd better find a friend besides you to help you.